# How to do async call in Rails and show the result in current view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a rails application, which based on the user input from selection drop down[call it as query page], hits the db backend and returns the result in a new page. Basically the page reloads and shows the result page[call it as result page].

I need to show the result page appended below the current elements of the query page. I have been trying for a while and not able to achieve this.

My query page:(rtes/r4d.html.haml)

```
= form_tag({:controller=>"r4d", :action=>"result"}, method: :get) do
  = label_tag(:q, "Trip Type: ")
  = select_tag(:q, options_for_select([["a",1],["b",2]),include_blank: 'Select one', required: true, class:"select")
  = submit_tag("Get Test Details")
```

My controller page which handles the db querying:(controllers/r4d_controller.rb)

```
class R4dController < ApplicationController
@@client=DynamoDBModel.new
def result

  result= case params[:q]
  when "1"
    @@client.1
  end

  @answer = result.value
  render "r4d/result" 
end
end
```

As you can see i am rendering the result to "r4d/result"

My result file: (r4d/result.html.haml)

```
%table{:id => "secondary"}
  %tr
    %th Key
    %th Value
%tr
  %td Trip ID
  %td #{answer}
```

How i can make this render to the same query page itself? One the user selects the drop down and submit a call needs to be made async and the result should be updated in the same page. If user makes another call, the existing result should be updated with the new one.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you'd like to submit the form via ajax and then render the results. Take a look at the Rails tutorial on the subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements

Comment: @mikwat Yes need to submit the form with ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the HAML this is what I'd do:

In the query page change the `form_tag` line to include `remote: true` so that the form submits with ajax. Like this:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "r4d", action: "result"}, method: :get, remote: true) do %>
```

Also put an empty div at the bottom of the page to receive the results in and give it an ID:

```
<div id="query-results"></div>
```

In the controller action specify that it responds to an ajax query by replacing the `render` call with a `responds_to` call like this:

```
@answer = result.value
respond_to :js
```

Then make the appropriate javascript file to put the response onto the page. It should be under `/app/views/r4d/` and in my case (no HAML) the file would be called `result.js.erb` to match the action name.
This would be the contents (I'm making use of jQuery here):

```
$('#query-results').html("<%= j render(partial: 'answer_table', locals: {answer: @answer}) %>");
```

This will render the HTML partial `/app/views/r4d/_answer_table.html.erb` passing it the answer as a local, then it will make the rendering into a javascript safe string (that's what the `j` does) then, when the js runs, it will replace any content in that div we made with the new rendering.

Now we just need the partial (`/app/views/r4d/_answer_table.html.erb):

```
<table id="secondary">
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Trip ID</td>
    <td><%= answer %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You'll have to do the converting to HAML yourself (or just put it through an online converting tool).

Comment: i have followed the exact steps but after clicking the query button, nothing happens and i am not getting any error message. Once i click the button, the button sinks in (ajax call is getting executed) and sinks out but the view is not updated. How can i debug this?

Comment: From the network tab in chrome, i can see, ajax call is being executed but getting failed. And this the error message shown in the response of the call. "SyntaxError in R4dController#result

/local/home/smuralik/Desktop/RTESWebsite_copy/src/OptimusRTESWebsite/rails-root/app/views/r4d/result.js.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/local/home/smuralik/Desktop/RTESWebsite_copy/src/OptimusRTESWebsite/rails-root/app/views/r4d/result.js.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #2):"

Comment: I forgot the closing parenthesis in the `render` call. I've fixed it in my answer now. You really need to be able to debug these things yourself. If you read the error message carefully it says it's expecting a `)` and it also tells you which file and which line to look in. That should be easy to debug.

Comment: Yes i have updated that. Now the call is getting executed and its  successful. But the view is not getting updated.

Comment: From the DOM, i can see, the table structure is there but its not visible. In the js.erb i replaced html with append. But it's still not visible.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't visible. You'll have to check what styles are being applied to the table and its parent element.

Comment: yes i got it. I was using attribute  display: none; for some other table and have used the same class for this class also. Now the table is visible in the view. I have searched my sites and all the examples are bit messy and hard to understand. Your approach was simple and clean. Can you suggest some links to follow?

Comment: In the meanwhile, how can i add a spinner or progress bar something like that until the call gets completed?

Comment: here's a link to a post that explains this sort of thing in detail: https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: here's another question on SO about how to put a spinner in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640646/ajax-loading-spinner-in-rails-4

Comment: my js for toggle is not working on the rendered html. any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169888/discussion-between-toby-1-kenobi-and-santhosh-kumar).